# How much data can you put on the stack?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I try to create a ~975KB array on the stack and it crashes.

```
const int size = 500;
cout << (sizeof(float)*size*size)/1024 << endl;
float myArray[size*size]; // crash
```

This seems like a very small amount of space. Is there any way to know how much space is available (total and currently) before I initialize a variable?

Comment: Which compiler and OS, it will differ, visual studio I think is 1 Meg.

Comment: Visual C++ 11 (x86) and Windows 7

Comment: I am sure a stack can be adjusted. That being said, why not use a `std::vector<float>` and avoid issue with limited stack?

Comment: On a Palm V it is something like 12kB or so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stack is limited in nearly all systems. How big it's allowed to be depends on the OS/Compiler combination. Putting VERY large amounts of data on the stack is a poor idea. Either use C++ standard types (e.g. `vector`) or use your own dynamic memory allocation. You never know when some other function adds a bit of extra stack, and all of a sudden, you go over the limit - best to not get anywhere near the max size of the stack.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual C++ the default stack size is managed by the linker option `/STACK` [(doc)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cxs58a6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). By default it is 1 MB.

Note that each new thread will have its own stack, and you can specify the initial size with parameter `dwStackSize` in function `CreateThread`. If it is 0 it will default to the one used in the linker command.

About your other questions, there is no way to query the current/maximum stack size. To avoid problems it is better to use the heap for any significant memory allocation.

Answer (score 3):

The default stack size for Visual Studio is `1MB`, as Andre said you can use `std::vector` to avoid this problem or you can dynamically allocate memory. You can adjust the stack size on Visual Studio using  [`/F`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx). If there is not a compelling reason to allocate the data on the stack it probably makes more sense to use another option.